# Cannot create eclipse RCP product

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have created a minimal RCP project with the Hello World example. I have selected Eclipse as the target platform since I want to modify the eclipse workbench (with the Hello World, Command example).

I have added the extension org.eclipse.core.runtime.products where I have specified:

```
ID: testID
name: Bob
```

On this extension I have right-clicked and  also created a new product with:

```
application*: test.product2
name*: name
```

I have run this plugin and verified that it prints "Hello, Eclipse world " when I press the button.

Next I have created a new Product configuration and added it to the PDE project folder.

On the overview pane I have kept the default settings:

```
ID: testID
Product: org.eclipse.platform.ide
Application: org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
```

On the Dependencies pane I have pressed "Add required plugin-ins". But when I run the product (pressing the green play button) I get the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.

Any ideas on how to create this minimal product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you press synchronize before launching your product, as  described in the [RCP tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#product_launch)?

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/images/product55.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/images/product55.gif)

> On the overview tab press synchronize and then press "Launch an Eclipse application".
>    **Synchronize will align your product configuration with the launch configuration**.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry.

You have to add org.eclipse.ui.ide.application to your dependencies.

Val